# Bandwidth, CPU & Memory stats returned in single line from terminal

Tags: bash, networking, terminal, monitoring

I'm trying to create a simple monitoring system that will show a graph of sales that is linked entirely to data of bandwidth, CPU and Memory stats as they relate to sales.  So if I sale 1 widget per 5 seconds, that will be contingent upon my bandwidth etc being above a certain threshold.  So I've formulated a way to do the graph but I'm just having a time getting the stats.  I can use any of a number of monitoring systems but I just need 1 line for bandwidth, CPU Usage, and Memory Usage once per second.  I made a python script that gets all the IP information from all interfaces.  But for if I had a script I could run from terminal that simply output a single line I could just pipe that to a file and then access the file to run my real time graph.

So for network I can use:

```
$ ifconfig
```

I pipe it into a json file for easy reference.

I can use:

```
$ free -m
```

for memory which I suppose I can pipe into a file as well

Then I could use:

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
```

for CPU and again pipe that.

Is there an easier way to do this?  So that I receive a single line for each command and can easily (more importantly quickly) send that information via Javascript or HTML5 FileReader to the graphing solution?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an easy way to aggregate the data that you want, but you could stick a bunch of commands together then pipe it out to whatever. I spent a little bit of time to come up with an example.

```
{
  printf '%s' '{"load":["'$(cut -d' ' --output-delimiter='","' -f-3 /proc/loadavg)
  printf '%s' '"],"net":{'
  tail -n+3 /proc/net/dev|awk -F' ' '{
    gsub(/:/,"");
    printf "\"%s\":{\"rxbytes\":\"%s\",\"rxpackets\":\"%s\",\"rxerrs\":\"%s\",\"rxdrop\":\"%s\",\"txbytes\":\"%s\",\"txpackets\":\"%s\",\"txerrs\":\"%s\",\"txdrop\":\"%s\"},",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$10,$11,$12,$13
  }'|sed 's/,$//'
  printf '%s' '},"mem":{'
  grep -E '^(MemTotal|MemFree|SwapTotal|SwapFree):' /proc/meminfo|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'|awk -F' ' '{gsub(/:/,""); printf "\"%s\":\"%s\",",$1,$2}'|sed 's/,$//'
  printf '%s' '}}'
}
```

You could squish it down into this:

```
{ printf '%s' '{"load":["'$(cut -d' ' --output-delimiter='","' -f-3 /proc/loadavg); printf '%s' '"],"net":{'; tail -n+3 /proc/net/dev|awk -F' ' '{ gsub(/:/,""); printf "\"%s\":{\"rxbytes\":\"%s\",\"rxpackets\":\"%s\",\"rxerrs\":\"%s\",\"rxdrop\":\"%s\",\"txbytes\":\"%s\",\"txpackets\":\"%s\",\"txerrs\":\"%s\",\"txdrop\":\"%s\"},",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$10,$11,$12,$13 }'|sed 's/,$//'; printf '%s' '},"mem":{'; grep -E '^(MemTotal|MemFree|SwapTotal|SwapFree):' /proc/meminfo|tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'|awk -F' ' '{gsub(/:/,""); printf "\"%s\":\"%s\",",$1,$2}'|sed 's/,$//'; printf '%s' '}}'; }
```

That should output some (valid) JSON that looks like this:

```
{"load":["0.00","0.01","0.05"],"net":{"lo":{"rxbytes":"2524231953","rxpackets":"1381864","rxerrs":"0","rxdrop":"0","txbytes":"2524231953","txpackets":"1381864","txerrs":"0","txdrop":"0"},"eth0":{"rxbytes":"2093914043","rxpackets":"2859952","rxerrs":"0","rxdrop":"0","txbytes":"1774385937","txpackets":"1485252","txerrs":"0","txdrop":"0"}},"mem":{"memtotal":"1692584","memfree":"20248","swaptotal":"917500","swapfree":"916288"}}
```

You could then add `| whatever` after the close curly to pipe it to whatever.

Comment: Wow...that's pretty awesome.  How did you come up with that?  I'm new to bash scripts...I know just some simple command type stuff.  Is there a super special book I can buy that will make me a bash super hero?

Comment: @Verber Most books on bash are awful and full of errors. I have never found any bash books that are anything above OK. If you want a solid reference, I highly recommend the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), and [Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php).

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestions...I almost just went credit card crazy on Amazon buying books

Comment: Man! This forum is so much nicer than Stack Overflow...No offense to anyone here but on SO it seems like I always have guys who have severe deficiencies that they like to take out on others.

Comment: Ya, Chris is right. Most BASH books kinda suck. In addition to the sites he gave, I find myself referring to http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ a ton... and lots of Googleing. That script I gave you is more string processing than scripting - if you find yourself wanting to manipulate data a lot you should look into learning a little bit of sed/awk/Perl/whatever the hot language of the day is. That thing up there is a freaking eye sore because of the JSON formatting. :)

Comment: @livingstaccato - TLDP's ABS is pretty bad as well, there are a lot of examples that are bug-ridden. I'd avoid recommending it.

Comment: @Chris - agreed on the examples, I use it more as a syntax reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [i3status](http://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html). It's not really designed for this purpose, but it sounds like it would fulfil your requirements quite nicely.

Comment: Hmm. Are you looking for a command that will concatenate all that information into a single line (like comma delimited), or are you looking for a way to get all that data from a single command in a normalized way?

Comment: I'm looking for a single command in a normalized way:  1 for bandwidth, 1 for CPU usage, 1 for Memory usuage.  I will be making calls to each of these individually so it's best to keep them separate.

Comment: I did take a look at i3status...looks pretty good.  Is there any way to only call it once?  Or will it just clip along by itself until you stop it?

Comment: @Verber `i3status | head -1`

Comment: ahhh!  that works.  The command below actually is what I will need.  Easy to grab it with JSON, using the new HTML File API...then into flotr2  should work awesome.  I'll throw up a little post when I'm done.